# Prove that $\mathbb R_l$ $\times$ $\mathbb R_l$ given the box topology has a countable dense subset.

Tags: general-topology, second-countable, box-topology

Let $\mathbb R_l$ be $\mathbb R$ given the lower limit topology, i.e. the topology generated by $\{[a, b)\subseteq \mathbb R|a<b\}$.

Prove that $\mathbb R_l$$\times$$\mathbb R_l$ given the box topology has a countable dense subset.

I don't know how to show this, can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You might want to show that $\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb R_l\times \mathbb R_l$

Comment: Why $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, so if you prove that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}_{l}\times\mathbb{R}_{l}$ then that shows that $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense countable subset

Comment: That make sense. Thank you. How about the box topology that the problem mentioned above?

Comment: The box topology on a finite product, like we have here, is just the same as the standard product.